# Minimax type principle for a self-adjoint operator acting on a Hilbert space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, matrix-analysis

Let $T\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ be a self-adjoint operator acting on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Suppose $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Define $$\lambda_k(T)=\sup\limits_{\substack{\mathcal{M}\subseteq \mathcal{H} \\ dim\mathcal{(M)}=k}}\inf\limits_{\substack{x\in \mathcal{M} \\ \Vert x\Vert=1}}\langle Tx,x\rangle.$$ Let $$\mu_k(T):=\inf\limits_{\substack{\mathcal{N}\subseteq \mathcal{H} \\ codim\mathcal{(N)}<k}}\sup\limits_{\substack{x\in \mathcal{N} \\ \Vert x\Vert=1}}\langle Tx,x\rangle.$$

I can see $\lambda_k(T)\leq\mu_k(T)$.

**Question:** Is $\lambda_k(T)=\mu_k(T)$?